# Testing Vue Composable with Global Variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I'm using a Vue composable to return an sequential number that is used to generate a unique ID for components e.g. for aria-controls.

```
/** Composable to return a sequential number */
import { onMounted, ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

/** Define a starting integer */
const globalItemNumber = ref(0)

/**
 * Increment and return the global item number
 */
export function useSequentialNumber() {
    const localItemNumber = ref(0)

    onMounted(() => (localItemNumber.value = globalItemNumber.value++))

    return { itemNumber: localItemNumber }
}
```

I've written a test for this script but when I run it I get the following error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run
@serenity-web/common-helpers:     [vue-composition-api] must call Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) before using any function.
@serenity-web/common-helpers:       3 |
@serenity-web/common-helpers:       4 | /** Define a starting integer */
@serenity-web/common-helpers:     > 5 | const globalItemNumber = ref(0)
```

How do I solve this problem? Is it best to abstract the global variable outside of my composable or is there a way of mocking it in the test script?

Comment: I gave up trying to get this to work. Adding `vue/composition-api` to Jest config caused a load of new errors when the test suite ran.

The original reason for the change was so that we could generate a unique ID for our components. We could use this library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-unique-id) but it's been written for Vue 2 and we're running Vue 3.

In the end, I just kept the logic in the component rather than using a composable which we're able to test using `createLocalVue` from `@vue/test-utils`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is specific to Vue 2, where composition API is available via `@vue/composition-api` plugin. The error means what it says, it's necessary to execute `Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)` before using composition API.

It's likely the same in the app itself but may require to treat it in a special way in tests. This requires to have the module:

```
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI);
```

And import it before anything else, specifically modules that use composition API on import (outside `setup` function):

```
import '.../composition-plugin';
...
```

This needs to be done for both application entry point and tests. This can be done once for all test suites in `setupFiles`.

Comment: Thanks Estus, do you know of any guides for configuring this in Jest?

Comment: See https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration .

Comment: I've done this but it still throws the same error for me

Comment: This most likely means that the file wasn't imported. You can confirm this by adding syntax error there.